# python.exe stopped working while importing image using opencv 3.1.0

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to import image using opencv 3.1.0 but I am getting the error shown in the attached image.
If I use opencv 2.4.13 instead of 3.1.0 I am successfully able to import and view the image.
While changing from opencv 2.4.13 to 3.1.0, I just replaced the 'cv2.pyd' of opencv 2.4.13 with 'cv2.pyd' of 3.1.0 file from the 'Ananconda' 'site-packages'.
Im am using Anaconda2 64 bit.

Here is the error screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: (1) Check whether you can display the image without Jupyter; (2) use matplotlib to display in Jupyter.